# Transitive and intransitive verb

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, verbs

1. *You have called London.*
2. *You have called in London.*
3. *You have called wrong person*.
4. *you have called to wrong person.*

All the sentences relating to "Phone." 
When the verb "Call" in transitive and when intransitive?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In the examples you give, the verb call should be used transitively

> Call me!
>
> Call London (here understood to mean "someone in London")
>
> Call the wrong number

Call can also be used without an object, but in these cases the object is usually implied by context.

> I'll call in the morning.  (implicitly meaning "call you..."